# Rails 3.2.12: Uninitialized constant Net::ReadTimeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have the following code (**connection.rb**):

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'openssl'

class Connection
    def request
        body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...'
        path = '/path'
        http = Net::HTTP.new('192.168.12.34', '1234')
        http.read_timeout = 60
        p "=1"
        http.request_post(path, body, {'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'})
        p "=2"
        ...
    rescue  Net::ReadTimeout => ex
        ...
    end
end
```

In the string **http.request_post(...)** I get the output:

```
"=1"
NameError: uninitialized constant Net::ReadTimeout
/home/user/invp/lib/connection.rb:76:in `rescue in request'
/home/user/invp/lib/connection.rb:26:in `request'
/home/user/invp/lib/tasks/task.rake:225:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My environment:

```
user@vm-dev:~/invp$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
user@vm-dev:~/invp$ rails --version
Rails 3.2.12
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **ruby 1.9.3** it raises **TimeoutError** Exception.
For **ruby 2.3.1** it raises **Net::ReadTimeout** Exception.

So you should use `rescue TimeoutError` or update your ruby version.

refs (search for read_timeout at the end of the page):

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

One more information: Net::ReadTimeout is a subclass of TimeoutError and it seems to be added on ruby-2.0.0:

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/ReadTimeout.html